# What role does the file "iis.config" play in the running of a web application on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment

We've recently finished development of a web application that works as expected.  When we handed it over to the ops team, they freaked out a little bit because we didn't supply the file "iis.config".  What is this file?  What does it do?

Edit:  It turns out its a proprietary file for our internal operations monitoring program or something.  My bad.

Comment: We can probably close this question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've personally never heard of it.

Perhaps they mean some kind of export of the IIS metabase?

I'd go back to them and honestly say, "What do you mean by iis.config, we don't have one of those."

If such a file commonly existed they'd be plenty of relavant Google results for "iis.config"

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a Web.config file in the project? If not, maybe that's what they meant.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Teknohippy. The closest thing I could find was:

[954872](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;954872) How to create and manage configuration backups in Internet Information Services 7.0